# Angular2: Proper way of accessing routing constant?

Tags: angular, router

Besides the AuthGuard I builded I just tried to build something like a guard function for the template. In my AuthService I got `public function isAuthorized(...)` which should check whether the user is authorized to **see** certain elements in the template.

So this is the HTML of my template

```
<button [routerLink]="['/somewhere']">
  Personen
</button>
```

and I got this route

```
{
  path: 'somewhere',
  canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  data: {
    permissions: [
      "add:student",
      "edit:student",
      "delete:student"
    ]
  }
}
```

So the needed permissions to activate the route are stored in the routing constant. I can access this constant in the `AuthService.isAuthorized(...)` easily. 
**But than I get the whole routing tree.**

Is there anyway doing something like this

```
<button [routerLink]="['/somewhere']"
        *ngIf=AuthService.isAuthorized(***)>
  Personen
</button>
```

where `***` returns the data of the route the button is bind to, in this case `/somewhere`.

Comment: sounds like you need to make use of ActivatedRoute, an injectable service the router provides that contains information about the current route

Comment: nope because the currently `ActivatedRoute` is not interesting when searching for the data of another route that is linked via the routerLink.

Comment: My bad, I realised I misread the question